# ADO.NET Возвращается неверный результат запроса

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

```
using (var SqlCon = await Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            int count;                
            object o = null;

            using (var cmdIdsCount =
                Command.InitializeCommandForInputIds
                    (@"GetPrivateMessagesAuthorsCount",
                        SqlCon, companionId,accountId))
            {//тут companionId=2,accountId=1
                o = await cmdIdsCount.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            }
       if (o == DBNull.Value || o == null)
                count = 1;
            else
                count = Convert.ToInt32(o);
  }

     internal static SqlCommand InitializeCommandForInputIds
       (string Function, SqlConnection SqlCon, int CompanionId, int AccountId)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Function, SqlCon);//тут CompanionId=2,AccountId=1 и ConnectionState=Open
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter par = cmd.Parameters.Add(AccountIdParameter, SqlDbType.Int);
        par.Value = AccountId;
        SqlParameter par1 = cmd.Parameters.Add(CompanionIdParameter, SqlDbType.Int);
        par.Value = CompanionId;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = CmdTimeout;
        cmd.Prepare();

        return cmd;
    }

     create table PrivateMessage
    (
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SenderAccountId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
AcceptorAccountId int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
PrivateText NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT N'Сообщение'    
     );
       insert into PrivateMessage values (1,2,N'Первое'),
      (2,1,N'Второе'),
        (1,2,N'Третье');
        go
          CREATE PROCEDURE GetPrivateMessagesAuthorsCount(@AccountId int=1, @CompanionId int=2)
         AS 
          BEGIN 
      set nocount off;
select count(Id)
from PrivateMessage 
where ((SenderAccountId=@AccountId and AcceptorAccountId=@CompanionId)
or (SenderAccountId=@CompanionId and AcceptorAccountId=@AccountId));

     end
    go
```

Почему-то при запросе в базу из программы count всегда=0 (o=0)

```
exec GetPrivateMessagesAuthorsCount 2,1
```

выдаёт 3. В чём может быть проблема и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, наверно, в строке

```
par.Value = CompanionId;
```

Comment: Слона-то я и не приметил...